# Powershell ISE form: How to stop Robocopy with function?

Tags: winforms, function, powershell, robocopy

I have a Windows Form created in PowerShell ISE, used to perform robocopy with a button.
It works fine, but the interface hangs when the robocopy is in progress, which I believe to be normal behaviour; something about the tasks running in the same thread.
**I want to be able to stop this robocopy process while it is running**, I need some help on how to do this.

I created a button and function to do this, I just need help on what to do in the function (and elsewhere if needed).
I've seen someone do this, but it doesn't seem to work for me; it outputs "Robocopy has been terminated" like it's supposed to but continues running through the files:

```
function start_robocopy {
robocopy "$($InputSource.Text)" "$($InputDestination.Text)" /ndl /e /np /tee /L | ForEach-Object { 
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() }
}

function stop_robocopy {
if (Get-Process -Name robocopy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {Stop-Process -Name robocopy -Force
$outputBox.AppendText("Robocopy has been terminated.")}
```

My full code here; see function template created at the bottom:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(850,582)
$form.add_Load($FormEvent_Load)

$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,110)
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(620,420)
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Both"
$outputBox.BackColor = "White"
$outputBox.ReadOnly = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox) 

#-----FORM END-----#
#-----BUTTONS START-----#

$StartBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StartBtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,80)
$StartBtn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,35)
$StartBtn.Text = "Start Robocopy"
$StartBtn.Add_Click({start_robocopy}) 
$form.Controls.Add($StartBtn)

$StopBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StopBtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,150)
$StopBtn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,35)
$StopBtn.Text = "Stop Robocopy"
$StopBtn.Add_Click({stop_robocopy})
$form.Controls.Add($StopBtn)

#-----BUTTONS END-----#
#-----INPUTBOXES START-----#

$InputSource = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputSource.Text="C:\test\src"
$InputSource.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,15) 
$InputSource.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,20)
$form.Controls.Add($InputSource)

$InputDestination = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputDestination.Text="C:\test\dst"
$InputDestination.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$InputDestination.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($InputDestination)

#-----INPUTBOXES END-----#
#-----FUNCTIONS START-----#

function start_robocopy {
robocopy "$($InputSource.Text)" "$($InputDestination.Text)" /ndl /e /np /tee /L | ForEach-Object { $outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n") }
}

function stop_robocopy {
#WHAT TO DO HERE?
}

#-----FUNCTIONS END-----#
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell background job so that you have control over it and it will not hang the UI.

Use Start-Job and capture the jobId and then use the same jobId to stop the job in stop_robocopy.

```
function start_robocopy {
    $source = Write-Host $InputSource.Text;
    $destination = Write-Host $InputDestination.Text;
    $jobId = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Job -ScriptBlock { robocopy "$source" "$destination" /ndl /e /np /tee /L | ForEach-Object { $outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n") } }}
    $global:newJobId = $jobId.Id
}

function stop_robocopy {
    $jobId = Get-Job -Id $newJobId;
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Stop-job -Id $jobId.Id }
    Write-Host "Stopped: $($jobId.Id)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The START function doesn't seem to do any copying anymore (the destination folder is empty even without /L and console outputs nothing), so it doesn't seem to do anything else now, than apply a number to a job (It worked in my original code example). Was I supposed to edit anything?
The STOP function correctly shows "stopped: [number]".

Comment: try with the updated answer. The background jobs can't access the form controls directly so passing source & destination as parameter. Also the progress can't be reported back to UI due to same limitation of background job.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We will have to do some more research, thank you for your input